# Nonlinear conjugate gradient update strategy by Dai and Yuan

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, na.numerical-analysis

In Nocedal and Wright book "Numerical Optimization", they describe on 
page 123 (formula 5.49) an update strategy for the beta parameter in 
the nonlinear conjugate gradient optimization, which was proposed by 
Dai and Yuan (SIAM Journal on Optimization, 10 (1999), pp. 177-182). 
Nocedal and Wright say that this strategy when used from 2nd iteration 
onwards guarantees global convergence. However, they don't mention 
what should be done during the first iterations. Is my guess, that it 
doesn't really matter which strategy used initially, correct?

Comment: You'd better post the relevant paper here, so we could take a look at it.

Comment: I don't have the access to the paper :( If I had, I probably wouldn't need to ask the question.

Comment: This strategy is also described here: http://www.math.lsu.edu/~hozhang/papers/cgsurvey.pdf

Comment: They might not, but it would seem safe to just start with Polak-Ribiere for the first few iterations (it having slightly better properties than Fletcher-Reeves), and then use that Dai-Yuan update in subsequent iterations.